# Azure - Configure disaster recovery and automatic failover for Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, disaster-recovery

We have our Azure Application Gateway provisioned in East US and our hot-stand by region is West US.

How do I configure the Azure Application gateway to support the disaster recovery with automatic failover? Would it impact the configured URLs /domains?

Answer (score 0):

Use Traffic Manager to distribute traffic across multiple application gateways in different datacenters for high availability, redundancy or fail over reasons

[image]